# Some issue with AntBuilder?

Tags: grails, ant, groovy

When i am deploying grails application, it's show classnotfound Exception in AntBuilder class?. Do i need to add any jar files to project? Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.AntMain
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.initProperties(Project.java:308)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.init(Project.java:295)
    at com.cabot.reader.BookController$_closure5.doCall(BookController.groovy:109)
    at com.cabot.reader.BookController$_closure5.doCall(BookController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and some more details about what you are doing, how you are deploying, what you are deploying to, etc? My psychic powers are limited this morning... ;)

Comment: I am deploying grails application war file to tomcat server.

Comment: Check to see if the Ant JARs actually do exist in your WAR file. Usually they get provided by Grails and sit in Grails' `lib` directory. Do you get the same issue if you are running your app with `grails run-app`? Before deploying it you can also try `grails run-war` which runs your WAR in an embedded container. You might simply have to copy the Ant JARs to the `lib` of your app.

Comment: it's running fine when i use grails run-app. But if i create a build and deploy in a Tomcat server it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ant jars are available in run-app because they're needed to run the scripts. But the jars aren't included in a war because in general Ant isn't used by the web app. But you can include them by declaring a dependency in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1'
   compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.7.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ant.

It does what Burt suggests, plus adds an ant dynamic property to your controller and other artifacts.